# Observer for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I'm trying to create an observer for a DataFrame. I've created a class that has a dataframe as an instance attribute. In this class I made an observer using the setter decorator, but when I modify or add a single column the setter is not called.

The class is like this

```
class ProvenanceTracker:
    def __init__(self, initial_df):
        self._df = initial_df
        self._copy_df=initial_df.copy()
        self.shape_change = False
        self.value_change = False
    def dataframe_is_changed(self):
        if self._df.shape==self._copy_df.shape:
            if not self._df.equals(self._copy_df):
                print('difference founded')
                self.value_change = True
            else:
                print('same df')
                pass
        else:
            print('shape changed detected')
            self.shape_change = True
    
    @property
    def df(self):
        return self._df
    
    @df.setter
    def df(self, new_value):
        self._df = new_value
        self.dataframe_is_changed()
        if self.shape_change:
            ##Do something
            self._copy_df=self._df.copy()
            self.shape_change = False
        elif self.value_change:
            ##Do something
            self._copy_df=self._df.copy()
            self.value_change = False
```

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))

tracker=ProvenanceTracker(df)
```

if I try to add a new column or modify a column the setter method isn't called

```
tracker.df['test']=np.zeros(tracker.df.shape[0])
```

if I do an operation on all the df the setter is called

```
tracker.df = tracker.df.replace(2, 5)
```

There is a way to call a method everytime the df changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried that myself but couldn't you implement `__set_item__()` and delegate to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/67a3d4241ab84419856b84fc3ebc9abcbe66c6b3/pandas/core/frame.py#L3028?

If you can live with reduced performance due to delegiation inheriting from dataframe and using the child class in your code would solve the problem at least.